# difference between built in ADT and data structures

Tags: java, python, data-structures, built-in, abstract-data-type

I've been doing alot of research but i have not been able to conclude why someone would choose to use a built in ADT or data structure over one you created yourself. What are benefits and drawbacks from using a built in over a data structure you created yourself, when would you use it and why?

Comment: Question: have you already built and exhaustively **tested** your personal library of data structures?

Comment: yes i have already written my own data structures like the queue, stack, tree, graph, linked list etc... but i was wondering what benefits arise from using the built in ones? @KevinAnderson

Comment: The benefit of the "built-in" data structures provided by a language is that they are a _de facto_ standard that most programmers in that language will know; other programmers would have to learn a new "same-but-different" API in  order to work on code that uses your private data structures.

Comment: Drawback: built-ins (both by design and out of necessity) won't have any intimate knowledge of _your_ particular application and so might not perform as well as custom data structures that you've carefully crafted and optimized to your specific needs.